# Find and replace string INSIDE a formula

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am trying to dynamically change some formula's on a dashboard based on a user button event.

The formula might look something like this:

> =SUMIFS(Table1[Amount];Table1[PickerName];$D$2;Table1[WayOfTransportGroup];H27;Table1[Date];">="&$I$2;Table1[Date];"<="&$I$3)

I want to change a small part of the formula

> Table1[PickerName];$D$2

into

> Table1[PickerName];$D$2;Table1[Type];"<>"&"gt 10 minuten";

I have written some code below. Which seems to work for normal strings, but it cant replace parts that are part of a formula.

If a cell has a value like **"Table1[PickerName];$D$2"** then the code works and the string is replaced. But if the cell value is changed to **="Table1[PickerName];$D$2"** (notice the = symbol) then the code can not replace the string anymore.

```
Sub ChangeScopeClick()

    Dim fnd As Variant
    Dim rplc As Variant

    fnd = "Table1[PickerName];$D$2"
    rplc = "Table1[PickerName];$D$2;Table1[Type];""<>""&""gt 10 minuten"";"

    For Each c In Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("C7:Y31")
        c.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next c

End Sub
```

I can't figure out how I am supposed to use the Replace function to change a string that is part of a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c.formula = replace(c.formula, fnd, rplc)
```

**update after comment**

I suspect the replace isn't generating a proper formula. The semi-colon or comma separator shouldn't really matter

try using

```
Dim tmp as string

tmp = Replace(c.formula, fnd, rplc)

debug.Print tmp

c.formula = tmp
```

Debug on each of the lines and even try manually putting the `tmp` output to the immediate window into a cell to make sure the references are correct

Comment: I tried that, same thing happens. Could it have something to do with using semicolons (;) instead of comma's (,) as my list seperator? When I debug the code the Watchlist seems to be using comma's instead of my choice of semicolons.

Comment: @TheNiers I don't think that should matter - have a look at my update

Comment: I changed the semicolons to comma's in my find and replace strings, e.g. from "Table1[PickerName];$D$2" to "Table1[PickerName],$D$2" and then your code does seem to work. Weird. But thanks!